# How do I join 2 tables but not duplicate rows?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with some duplicate data.  Would a JOIN be used to merge the 2 tables into a 3rd table OR would you merge table 2 (with updated info) into table 1 (older data)?

I know this seems a peculiar question but the original database has extra columns the newer database (#2) doesn't contain.  When I've tried to merge them, I keep destroying the older rows with the extra data.

The database in this case is zip codes, city names etc.  I'm trying to determine how to INSERT the missing zip code rows.  In this instance, zip code are unique.  Columns are `zip_code`, `city`, `lat` and `lon`.  Table 1 has unique columns like `time_zone`.

I tried to do INSERT NOT IN but as I said, I keep screwing it up.  Could somebody show me the proper way to do this with my example columns without flubbing it up again? I can add my other columns later to the statement once I see the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was easier to not merge into a 3rd table.  And I found this method worked perfectly.  It allows you to merge table B into table A where a matching row doesn't already exist on table A.  In this case a zip code in zip_code.

```
INSERT INTO testing.table_name
(
zip_code,
city,
lat,
lon) 

SELECT zip-new.zip_code,
    zip-new.city,
    zip-new.lat,
    zip-new.lon,

FROM testing.zip-new

WHERE zip_code not in (
  SELECT zip_code 
  FROM testing.table_name
 )
```

Hopefully it can help someone else.

Comment: I take it from this that you don't actually want to merge 2 tables into a 3rd (ie, what your original question seemed to say you wanted), rather just add details that do not already exist in that table. If so an easier way would be to make zip_code a unique key and use `INSERT IGNORE....`. If you don't want to do that then instead of using `IN (subquery)` do a LEFT OUTER JOIN to the table with a WHERE clause to check that the result is NULL (ie, no matching record). This should be far more efficient.

Comment: I did ask which way would you do it.  It turns out that merging into the 3rd table would be more of a pain.

Comment: That depends on whether you want a new table or not. Whether that is required or not makes a pretty dramatic change.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is a FULL OUTER JOIN. MySQL doesn't directly support full outer joins, but you can emulate them with a couple of LEFT JOIN queries, and unioning the results together.

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*
FROM table_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2
ON table_1.somecolumn = table_2.somecolumn
UNION 
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*
FROM table_2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_1
ON table_1.somecolumn = table_2.somecolumn
```

This would need some work as you need to define which columns you want to join on, and which ones you use for your 3rd table.

EDIT

As it seems you do not require the data to go into a 3rd table, then 2 easy options

Set zip_code to be a unique key and then use the following:-

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO testing.table_name
(zip_code, city, lat, lon) 
SELECT zip-new.zip_code, zip-new.city, zip-new.lat, zip-new.lon
FROM testing.zip-new
```

This will ignore any attempt to insert a record for a zip code that already exists.

Of if you want to check, do it as a join (which should be more efficient that using *NOT IN (subquery...)* syntax

```
INSERT INTO testing.table_name
(zip_code, city, lat, lon) 

SELECT zip-new.zip_code,
    zip-new.city,
    zip-new.lat,
    zip-new.lon,
FROM testing.zip-new
LEFT OUTER JOIN testing.table_name ON testing.zip-new.zip_code = testing.table_name.zip_code
WHERE testing.table_name.zip_code IS NULL
```

Comment: So the *'s would be the column names?

Comment: The * means all column names. But here the first query gets all records from table_1 whether they have a match or not on table_2. In this case not sure which fields you want from table_1 and which from table_2